# scrapy keyError: z (freebsd)

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, freebsd, mariadb, scrapy-shell

I am trying to install scrapy 0.24 in freebsd (MariaDB) system but when I try to run it I have an "keyError: 'z'" which I don't know what it means... I tried to debug it with no success.

```
File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('Scrapy==0.24.4', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 60, in run
self.crawler_process.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 92, in start
if self.start_crawling():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 124, in start_crawling
return self._start_crawler() is not None
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 139, in _start_crawler
crawler.configure()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 47, in configure
self.engine = ExecutionEngine(self, self._spider_closed)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 65, in __init__
self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 66, in __init__
self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 50, in from_crawler
return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 31, in from_settings
mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/media.py", line 29, in from_crawler
pipe = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py", line 52, in from_settings
return cls(store_uri)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/files.py", line 150, in __init__
self.store = self._get_store(store_uri)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/files.py", line 170, in _get_store
store_cls = self.STORE_SCHEMES[scheme]
KeyError: 'z'
```

I'll try to install also scrapy 0.22 in freebsd just in case that could be the problem

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If anyone is interested, I have installed scrapy 0.22 and I get same error... keep trying

Comment: Solved!! the problem was about the slashes in settings.py (in unix you should write / instead of \ ) hehe... hope it helps someone